# how to solve default activity not found error for custom launcher

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi i am using latest android studio 2.3.1
I am creating custom launcher application. Few months ago it is working perfectly but today it gives me an error that default activity not found in manifest. Can anyone solve my problem. Here is my manifest code. Thanks in advance.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="Warriors Launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AppsListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Trans">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AppGridActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Trans">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AppLauncher"
        android:theme="@style/Trans">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`  as like-

```
    <activity
        ---->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            -----
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks fr your support

Comment: Yes, i use this code with my code. i used both Launcher and Default category on same activity, and it works. Thanks

Comment: Then you should check it as a correct answer. I am glad that it helped. :)